# IPhone controlled RC car

Tags: software, research

I have an R.C car and there is a program in my computer in which I can code the car to perform movements.I would like to have an application with a visual design.Where it shows the cars path.

Is there available software code for this? Saves me lots of time.

Comment: I voted to close this question as a shopping request question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably have more success with Android, i.e. NXT Remote Control took me 30 seconds to find.